# Stored procedure with string parameters, how to get it work?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure which is taking two arguments to retrieve some data from customers table.

Below is the stored procedure, it does not retrieve any data, however when I just type the select query, it works.

Can somebody help me to see where is the problem?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RecordsByColumnSearch]
    @field VARCHAR(50),
    @search VARCHAR(50)
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM Customers
    WHERE @field = @search
```

Executing this stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC dbo.RecordsByColumnSearch @field = CustomerID, @search = ALFKI;
```

does not return any data, while running this query does:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE CustomerID = 'ALFKI';
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (which appears to be SQL Server).

Answer (score 6):

You can't do what you want using regular SQL.  You need dynamic SQL.  I would recommend:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RecordsByColumnSearch] (
    @field Varchar(50),
    @search Varchar(50)
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = '
select c.*
from Customers c
Where @field = @search
';

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@field', @field);
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@field nvarchar(50)', @search=@search;

END;
```

`sp_executesql` executes SQL statements and allows you to pass in parameters.  That is the best way to pass parameters in.  Unfortunately, that doesn't work for column names, so they still need to be passed in by munging the query string.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon, however when I execute, it gives me an error

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@search".

Comment: @Zoe . . . That was a silly error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff just a dummy question, let's say he is using SQL server, why can't he just write normal SP, why do he need to create the `@sql`

Comment: @Jacky . . . Because the OP wants to pass in a column name.  You need dynamic SQL to do that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oh i see, i didn't realize he is passing a column name with `@field` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @field varchar(40)
declare @search varchar(40)

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = 'select c.* from Customers c where '+@field+' = '''+@search +''''

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

For Using Stored Procedure

create proc recordsbycoulmnsearch
@field  varchar(50),
@search varchar(50)
 as
 begin
    declare @sql    nvarchar(max)

```
set @sql = 'select c.* from customer c where '+@field+' = '''+@search+''''

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

end

exec recordsbycoulmnsearch 'Columnname','searchid'

Try this dynamic query..

Comment: While this works, it leaves open the possibility of SQL injection. Using sp_executesql with the proper parameters will avoid that.